# Jest TypeScript tests failing in Jenkins

Tags: typescript, jenkins, jestjs, jenkins-pipeline, ts-jest

We have a React / TypeScript project and are using Jest + ts-jest as our test runner. Everything works fine locally but fails when running in our Jenkins CI.

Here is a snippet from the Jenkins console:

```
No tests found, exiting with code 1
In /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/fix-jenkins-tests
  403 files checked.
  testMatch: **/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x), **/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x) - 38 matches
  testPathIgnorePatterns: /lib/, /node_modules/ - 0 matches
  testRegex:  - 0 matches
Pattern:  - 0 matches
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

The odd part is that Jest says "No tests found" but also says "testMatch: ... 38 matches"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Teammate of asker here, this ended up being a bit more subtle. 
The culprit here is the /lib/ in the testPathIgnorePatterns. testPathIgnorePatterns match against the *full path* of any test files found by testMatch or testRegex.

As it turns out, the working directory for our Jenkins instance was something like `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace` so the testMatch would find all of our test files, but then the testPathIgnorePatterns would match them all on /lib/ and exclude them all.

The correct way to exclude the '/lib/' folder in an environment-agnostic way was to use the `<rootDir>` token like so

`testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/lib/',
  ],`